# Principle of Locking -- in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I got some problems with my codes that i can't tell.
Will u finger it out for me?
And can you help answer some of the following questions?
This `class`'s functions may be called in multi-thread situation.

```
#import "FileHandler.h"
#import <pthread.h>

#define kJsonFilePath [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/foo/jsonFile.json"]

static pthread_mutex_t _lock;

@implementation FileHandler

+ (void)initialize
{
    if (self == [YWMultiAccountsHandle class]) {
        pthread_mutex_init(&_lock, NULL);
    }
}

+ (void)writeIntoTheFileWithArray:(NSArray *)arr
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&_lock);
    NSMutableArray *muArr = [NSMutableArray array];
    [arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if (![obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            [muArr addObject:[obj get_keyValues]];
        }
        else
        {
            [muArr addObject:obj];
        }
    }];
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&_lock);

    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[muArr copy] options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    pthread_mutex_lock(&_lock);
    [data writeToFile:kJsonFilePath atomically:YES];
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&_lock);
}
```

1.Can i remove the `pthread_mutex_unlock(&_lock);` and `pthread_mutex_lock(&_lock);` in the middle?
2.Is there any problem in this class?
3.when the `_lock` will release and dealloc?
4.Is it thread safe?

Comment: Does not look like the locking makes any sense here, in both places. Concurrent calls will overwrite each other anyway, wether they happen at the same time or not, they do not read, modify or share state. The result will always be that one writes and the other overwrites but there should be no corrupt writes since the actual writes happen atomically.

Comment: @luk2302 so is that means, there is no need to add any lock in writeIntoTheFileWithArray: ?

Comment: @luk2302 thx for your feed back. But i am really confused about the lock and the multi-threads. is there any tutorials about them?